# How does "Business Objects" generate SQL?

Tags: sql, join, business-objects, sql-generation

Is there a set of rules that Business Objects uses to generate SQL? I have just run into situation where the order of joins actually seriously affected the performance and it would be really nice to know what parameters does BOBJ use to decide how to order the tables.

Comment: Does the product's documentation mention their algorithm at all?

Comment: The DB engine can rearrange the join order when it constructs the execution plan. (unless for example the `FORCE ORDER` query hint is specified)

Comment: @Magnus Thanks for your reply. 
I know that. The thing is that we were not intentionally applying one extra condition on one join and in this case, the order of JOINs in the generated SQL is very important.

Comment: @jonnyGold Thanks for your reply. Have not found anything regarding the topic yet.